# Load data from file when initializing data in H2

Tags: mysql, h2

I have a big data.sql file to load data into H2 when application starts up.

This is portion of my data.sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER AU_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE_A FOR EACH ROW
CALL "com.trigger.MyTrigger";

LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE 'C:/Users/mytextfile.delim'
REPLACE INTO TABLE TABLE_B
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(name, age, etc);
```

When I start the application, all the queries in data.sql run fine but as soon as it reaches `LOAD DATA...` part, I get this error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "LOAD[*] DATA LOW_PRIORITY INFILE ... [42000-197]

```
This is my application.yml spring.datasource.url
=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MYSQL
spring.datasource.username: myusername
spring.datasource.password: mypassword
driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue please? Any hint?

Comment: iam wondering how much MySQL supports H2 has when running in mode=mysql..if i check MySQL Compatibility Mode on the http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html page it's looks like pretty limitted to basic queries.

Comment: H2 seams to support `CSVREAD`  source http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#fulltext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by programatically configuring H2.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {        
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .setName("mydb;MODE=MYSQL")
            .addScript("mariadb.sql") //this file name has to be different than data.sql otherwise Springboot will pick data.sql automatically and this will also run.
            .build();       
    return db;
}
```

Then create another bean that depends on above datasource:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("dataSource")
public Void string(DataSource db) throws SQLException {
    //read file using whatever means. I used Scanner and delimeted it myself. 
    final Connection connection = db.getConnection();
    //here use the prepratedStatements 
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(Insert xyz); //lookup how to use PreparedStatement. 
    }
```

It is important to create a separate bean that will insert the data into tables. You can also run prepared statement inside DataSource bean, but it didn't work for me. So I inserted data outside of it after DataSource is all set.